# The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Before selecting a page, the default home index page is showing. But when I am selecting a particular page it is showing this error.

> The resource cannot be found
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly. Requested URL:
>   /Administration/Companies Version Information: Microsoft .NET
>   Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18045

I am developing using MVC4 Razor (Visual Studio 2012). I have tested Can anybody Help. Any thoughts.

Comment: Do you have the neccessary controllers & views?

Answer (score 1):

You usually don't have real "pages" in MVC. You got Controllers and Views.

You Access these pages by /controllername/methodname

Inside that method you return a view

Make Sure you use the right structure and enter the correct routes in the global.ascx. If you still got problems, post your routes here.